# Is it possible to add default "Select" option in data-filter-control attribute in cshtml?

Tags: jquery, html, razor

I have a dropdown box in my html page.I have used the following query.

```
<th data-filter-control="select" data-field="Violation_name ">Violation Name</th>
```

where "Violation_name" is a column name from database. Can I add "Select" as a placeholder for the dropdown box?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, if you are using Razor and ASP.NET use the `@Html.Dropdownlistfor(x=>x.Property, IEnumerable<Something>(or select list),string lable(optional), object attributes)`

now object attributes can be written as `new { placeholder="Select", data....}`
Also try using new

```
SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Some value))), 
                    "Select Somevalue")
```

as your argument to the IEnumerable list

`@Html.Dropdown` works in the same way except you have to specify the name of the property

Comment: Thanks.. Is it possible to add code to this particular line itself? like `<option></option>` tag?

Comment: You will have to either use a forloop in your razor to create that effect or custom dropdown extention method using MVCHtmlString class to achieve that, but the above method will give you the placeholder in an option tag